# Software only partially updated on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, update-manager

I have found on my system (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit), that when there are software updates, not all are considered by the "update manager" system.
I mean that, for instance, there are 10 packages to update, but in the "update manager" window only 7 are listed. It seems that some updates are ignored, and I don't understand why.

If I use Synaptic, I can see that there are still some updates to apply, but the "update manager" system continues to ignore them, even after a couple of weeks. One time, I have applied all the updates with Synaptic, but after some time there was again some updates ignored by the "update manager" system.

Someone has any clue about this "strange" behavior?

(*I'm sorry for my bad English*)

Comment: What is the output of `sudo apt-get upgrade?`, are the packets mentioned there?

Comment: Yes. Actually I have these 8 packages mentioned: "gir1.2-nautilus-3.0 language-pack-it language-pack-it-base libkdecore5 libnautilus-extension1a nautilus nautilus-data xdg-utils", but the update manager "ignore" them.

Comment: @Vosaxalo: But what does `sudo apt-get upgrade` *do* if you try to upgrade it? Does it say that any dependencies are not met? Does it give an error?

Comment: @saiarcot895 Not at all. I have no problems with the updates. I can use sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade or use Synaptic without any issue. The only problem is that with the "official" update manager some packages seems to be ignored. I know that I can just use the commands in a terminal, but the update manager is supposed to do the same job. So I have opened this question to find out if this is a problem only for me or not.

Comment: @Vosaxalo: The only thing that I can think of is that in the Software Updates settings, the auto-update is for security updates only, and so the Update Manager only does security updates. Synaptic and `apt-get` don't follow such settings.